# How to write a Unittest case to check the return view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, unit-testing

```
 AdvertisementDataContext db = new AdvertisementDataContext(); //make an object so that we can retrieve data from database

        public ActionResult Index()
        {

            var advertisement = db.Advertisements.ToArray(); // retrieve data from database
            return View(advertisement); // we return the object to the index view
        }
```

I write a test case for this code.but it's not work it gives the error

```
Error   1   The type 'System.Data.Entity.DbContext' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
```

my test method is

```
[TestMethod]

public void TestIndex() {
    Bartering.Models.AdvertisementDataContext db = new Bartering.Models.AdvertisementDataContext();
    AdvertisementController controller = new AdvertisementController();
    ViewResult result = controller.Index() as ViewResult;
    Assert.AreEqual(db.Advertisements, result.ViewBag);


}
```

please help me to solve this or help me to write a test case for that method..

Comment: The error message tells you exactly what you need to do: add a reference to the `EntityFramework` assembly. Have you tried that?

Comment: Also, please read http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2013/09/19/casting-vs-quot-as-quot-embracing-exceptions.aspx for your use of `as`...

Answer (score 2):

If you are serious about *unit* testing this, I think you should wrap the data context in a mockable class and mock that in your test using a mocking framework like [NSubstitute](http://nsubstitute.github.io/). Otherwise your test will probably try to hit some database, which is inappropriate for a unit test.